# List Out all video from url

Tags: iphone, video

I am trying to list out all Video from a url. For this i m sending an request to "You Tube"
url as "http://www.youtube.com/" and want to list out all available video . But i didn't get anything from that request ? any idea or any documentation hint ?

Comment: what language/platform do you use?

Comment: For iPhone, Objective C language

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There **are** utilities for downloading youtube videos (for example Linux has [youtube-dl](http://bitbucket.org/rg3/youtube-dl/wiki/Home)), but it's not uncommon for sites with large numbers of downloadable files to prevent attempts to simply download everything - and even though you said you wanted to list rather than download all the videos, that's unfortunately what it would suggest to a website administrator.

Besides, files on youtube are not accessed by simple urls like http://www.youtube.com/*filename*

Something more is required. I don't think you can treat the (what is it?) 11 character alphabet soup as a *filename*, it's a parameter passed to the software which streams back the video.

EDIT: youtube-dl is a command-line program in Linux and probably BSD. You need to know the URL of the Youtube video so you can type (for example)

```
youtube-dl http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Z1JZ9O15280
```

If you had a list of these URLs you could put them in a file and make a bulk download script - but that takes us back to your original question.

In Firefox I would right-click on a link to a Youtube video and choose 'copy link location'. Then paste the URLs one at a time into a text file. But this question is drifting away from mere programming...

Comment: i m also thinking like that. simply, by request i didn't get... something more is required ..  can u tell me how to retrieve these video ..
thanks for suggestion

Comment: youtube-dl is a command line utility and you call it by specifying something like youtube-dl http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Z1JZ9O15280 at a prompt. In other words you need to know the URL of each file before can you download it. If you had a list in a file, you could turn it into a bulk download script, but as we discussed earlier, there doesn't seem to be a simple way to obtain a list (short of going to Youtube and copying them from the screen)

Comment: sorry, the URL in the last comment is corrupted. Comments are difficult to format. I'll go back and edit my original answer.

Comment: here, again question is how to get specific url for each video ....like v=Z1JZ9O15280 ? this things ....

Comment: In Firefox I right-click on a link to a Youtube video and choose 'Copy Link Location' (that is, copy to the clipboard) then it can be pasted into a text file. In IE7 that would be 'Save Shortcut As'. The best place to find links to Youtube videos is on Youtube's website, of course.

Comment: but in app 'Copy Link Location' is not possible . even that value also changed time to time . and also list of video also changed ... that is main problem ?